# Magento 2 - can't upload images in CMS (File validation failed.)

Tags: magento2, image, cms, magento2.3.2, upload

I try to upload a small (900 KB) .jpg image to my CMS Site, but I get **File validation failed.**

I made sure that I have all necessary permissions as stated in the [magento documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html).

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

But the error still appears. I am using Magento 2.3.2 with PHP Version 7.2.5

Comment: Try to upload another image, maybe image is corrupted.

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang, I tried another image, same error.

Comment: try with png, or other image from internet

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang, I tried a .png image from the internet, same error

Comment: Can you please check the var/log, you can find the hint fro there !!!

Comment: @Dhrumin, there is no error logged. I also checked the vhost error log

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the missing PHP module "fileinfo".

I installed it with `zypper in php7-fileinfo` (open suse)

If you are using ubuntu then the package name might be different, probably `php7.0-fileinfo`

**NOTE:** Don't forget to restart the webserver after it.